# Multiple-column keys with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, innodb

I have a database table which has a compound primary key `(id_a, id_b)`. That's not what they're actually called but I am simplifying for this question. `id_a` is a foreign key and `id_b` is just an integer, "sequence number" so to speak. I cannot just make `id_b` auto_incrementing because it is not allowed for the InnoDB storage engine (as it is not the first field in the compound key).

I would like to make it so that these objects can be "grouped" with `id_a`, so for example:

```
id_a    id_b
----------------
1       1
1       2
2       1
2       2
2       3
```

and the result of inserting a row with (`id_a=1`) should automatically set `id_b=3`. I would like to avoid using database locks, especially since there is no need to lock the entire table when concurrent inserts with different `id_a` should totally be allowed.

I am accessing this database through Python via SQLAlchemy (using the ORM), although I suspect this question can be answered agnostically with regards to the client side (pure MySQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT coalesce(max(ID_B),0)+1 
FROM yourTable 
WHERE ID_A = '1'`

However, without the locking, you run the risk of getting duplicate ID_B values, so you'd have to handle duplicate key errors on the insert statements.  Either "Retry" within code automatically for a set number of times or error and force user to try again.